# ThinkPad E15 Gen 2 TrackPoint is not working with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kernel, lenovo, thinkpad, trackpoint

I have Ubuntu 20.04 with kernel version 5.8.0-43-generic. TrackPoint (red dot on keyboard) is not working (nor it buttons) with ubuntu 20.04. I have installed synaptics drivers, it improved TouchPad experience, but did not help with TrackPoint. Here is out put of `xinput`:

```
    amareyah@pc: xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan Touchpad                             id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Elan TrackPoint                           id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated I           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]

amareyah@pc: xinput list-props 12
Device 'Elan TrackPoint':
    Device Enabled (179):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (181): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (355):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (356):   0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (357):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (358):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (359):   0, 0, 1
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (360): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (361): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (362):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (363):    0
    libinput Accel Speed (364): 0.007353
    libinput Accel Speed Default (365): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (366):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (367):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (368):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (369): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (370): 0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (302): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (303):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (304):    0, 0
    Device Node (305):  "/dev/input/event5"
    Device Product ID (306):    1267, 14
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (371):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (372):   1
    
amareyah@pc: xinput list-props 11
Device 'Elan Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (179):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (181): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (312): 1
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (313):   2.500000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (314):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (315):    8.455882
    Synaptics Edges (316):  122, 2938, 110, 1934
    Synaptics Finger (317): 25, 30, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (318):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (319):   161
    Synaptics Tap Durations (320):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (321):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (322):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (323):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (324):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (325): -73, 73
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (326): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (327):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (328): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.054363, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (329):    0
    Synaptics Locked Drags (330):   0
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (331):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (332): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (333):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (334): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (335):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (336): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (337):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (338): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (339):    10, 200
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (340): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (341):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (342): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (343):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (344):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (345):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (346):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (347): 31, 31
    Synaptics Area (348):   0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (349):  1530, 0, 1676, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (350): 18, 18
    Device Product ID (306):    1267, 14
    Device Node (305):  "/dev/input/event4"
```

I've tried adding "psmouse.proto=imps" as a kernel boot parameter, it solved issue, but then my TouchPad lost it functions (it became sluggish, it lost two finger scrolling and etc.). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem some time ago and solved it this way: (it might be out of date)

create (as sudo) `/usr/lib/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-thinkpad-trackpoint.conf` and add via vim or nano:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier  "ThinkPad TrackPoint"
    MatchProduct    "TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Option      "EmulateWheel"      "true"
    Option      "EmulateWheelButton"    "2"
    Option      "XAxisMapping"      "6 7"
    Option      "YAxisMapping"      "4 5"
EndSection
```

You'll need to logout or reboot

Comment: In /usr/lib/X11 there was no directory xorg.conf.d, so I've created it and put there file 60-thinkpad-trackpoint.conf with content given by you; rebooted computer. No result on my trackpoint - dead the same way as it was before...